# show text instead of radiobutton numbers in codeigniter

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, radio-button

I have a pair of radiobutton which you have for "yes" the value of 1 and not the value of 0.

Now this works perfectly, it registers me and shows it correctly, if you select "yes" it shows me the number 1 and if I select "no" it shows me the number 0.

What I need is that instead of showing me the numerical values, it shows me the text "YES" or "NO", since it seems unpleasant to show the numbers.

Is it possible to do this?
This is my code!

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->
 <legend>NOTIFICADO</legend>
     <label>
            <input type="radio" name="notificado" value="1" checked="checked"> YES
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="notificado" value="0"> NO
        </label>

<br>
```

And with this line of code I show the value

```
<td><label>Notificado:</label> <p class="notificado" ><?php echo $registrocompra->notificado; ?></p>   </td>
```

Comment: `value="YES"` etc.

Comment: Please explain the [tag:java] question tag as I don't yet see how this question relates to programming in the Java language.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `value` attribute of `input` with any other value of your choice, e.g.:

```
 <input type="radio" name="notificado" value="no"> NO
```

You also can modify output instead:

```
<td>
    <label>Notificado:</label> 
    <p class="notificado" ><?php echo $registrocompra->notificado == '1' ? 'Yes' : ''No; ?></p>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you! The second option worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
    <td>
        <label>Notificado:</label> 
        <p class="notificado" ><?php echo "".$registrocompra->notificado == '1' ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?></p> 
  </td>
```